# git clone file contain non-ANSI chars into ANSI encoding

Tags: git, encoding

i'm using git for windows(2.30.1), clone the repos from dev.azure.com.
The issue is: the file contains non-ANSI chars, but after i clone it the file encoding is ANSI(notepad++), and the non-ANSI display as "?" or in some special chars.

Below is what i have tried:
1> Check with others, they can download it correctly.
2> i copy the non-ANSI chars at the begin of the file, then it can be downloaded as UTF-8 and working

I guess git may guess the encoding base on the first n chars.
Can please help to advise how to solve? any configuration that can configure this at the git for windows client?

Comment: What encoding does it use?  UTF-8?  "ANSI" encoding usually means Windows-125x, and that's now considered an obsolete encoding.  Try configuring your editor or other program to use UTF-8 instead.

Comment: @bk2204, thanks for your reply. the file was stored in Azure repos, i don't there is a property to display the original encoding.   I just join the project, so don't want to change the existing file encoding, and want to download it file with the correct encoding like other colleagues

Comment: Are you sure the file are different, and not an issue of your editor? Did you put some special `git config` item (as global setting)? (or when you setup your git)? Check `.git` directory on your "home" folder.